# How to modify environment variables on elastic beanstalk with previous non successful application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My container is failing to startup due to environment variables not being present.

```
[Instance: i-036f3811889751cbe] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...cker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Wed Jun 28 12:06:38 UTC 2017: nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "limit_except" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:15. Check snapshot logs for details. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

I can't set the environment variables because that will  to reinitialize the previous non succesfull aplication.

Do I have to terminate the whole environment?

I'm trying to set the environment variable for a new application version that hasn't been deployed / initialized yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember where I found the solution, but essentially I solved this by setting the instances to 0, setting the environment variables, and then setting the instances to 1.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the answer to this too, but I couldn't find a good way to set my instances to 0. Instead, I modified my app to just do something simple that won't break. In my case it was to just modify the Dockerfile to just run a Python http server (assuming that your container installs Python):

`ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "http.server"]`

This will allow the container to run in EB. Then you can set the variables, then change the Dockerfile back.